# How to optimize code to not using `.compute` and without using `!!` in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have following code:

```
val resultMap = mutableMapOf<String, MutableMap<String, Int>>()
val counter = mutableMapOf<String, Int>() //Meta data

val keywordSearch = keywords.map { it to """(?i)\b($it)\b""".toRegex() }
        
        keywordSearch.forEach { (keywordString,keywordRegex) ->
            if (keywordRegex.containsMatchIn(jobAd.toString())) {
                counter.putIfAbsent(keywordString, 0)
                counter.compute(keywordString) { _, v -> v!! + 1 }
                resultMap[weekNumber]!!.compute(keywordString) { _, v -> v!! + 1 }
            }
        }
```

Is there anyway to optimize this code by not using `!!` inside the counter function ->
{ _, v -> v`!!` + 1 } for counter and resultmap

Comment: Why use the putIfAbsent and not just do `(v ?: 0) + 1`

Comment: @DownloadPizza that looks like an answer to the question to me. why write it as a comment? ;)

Comment: @IvoBeckers Yes I realized that as well, the putIfAbsent confused me

Comment: @Tenfour04 , i have added the types.

Comment: @DownloadPizza, what do you mean? Can you show code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually this behaviour is best achieved using [merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) rather than `putIfAbsent` and `compute`:

```kotlin
if (keywordRegex.containsMatchIn(jobAd.toString())) {              
  counter.merge(keywordString, 1, Int::plus) 
  resultMap[weekNumber]!!.merge(keywordString, 1, Int::plus)
}
```

If the key wasn't already in the map, it sets the value to 1.

If the key was already in the map, it combines the previous value with the new value (1) using the given merge function, here `Int::plus`, which is a short-hand for `{ old, new -> old + new }`.

Also, instead of `resultMap[weekNumber]!!` you can use `resultMap.getValue(weekNumber)` which will fail with a better error message if the key is absent.

Answer (score 1):

Id use the elvis operator ?:

```
if (keywordRegex.containsMatchIn(jobAd.toString())) {              
  counter.compute(keywordString) { _, v -> (v ?: 0) + 1} 
  resultMap[weekNumber]!!.compute(keywordString) { _, v -> v!! + 1 }
}
```

the elvis operator uses v when v not null, otherwise it uses the 0 in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Might be nice to create a separate extension function for this specific case so your logic code is easier to read.

```
fun <K> MutableMap<K, Int>.incrementValue(key: K): Int {
    return (getOrDefault(key, 0) + 1).also {
        this[key] = it
    }
}
```

```
if (keywordRegex.containsMatchIn(jobAd.toString())) {              
  counter.incrementValue(keywordString) 
  resultMap[weekNumber]!!.incrementValue(keywordString)
}
```